# Newline Linux Fortran output incompatible with windows

Tags: linux, windows, newline, compatibility, gfortran

I have a Fortran program originally compiled on Windows, it gets plain input text files and produces plain output text files write the write command:

```
  do fig=180,0,-1
    write(jfil,'(i3.3,2x,f7.5,1x,f7.4,1x,2(1x,f9.4,1x,a3),2(2x,i3),2(1x,f9.4,1x,a3))') &
    fig,xc(fig),cc(fig),(Pcav(je),fcav(je),je=1,2),agav,agad,(Pcad(je),fcad(je),je=1,2)
  enddo
```

I need to compile and run it on Linux but I have problems with endline char compatibility when I read on windows the output files.
This is what i expect on the notepad program on windows

```
177  0.99947  0.2519     9.5946 com   36.4488 exp    3  357    9.5882 asp   36.6517 sca
176  0.99905  0.3358     9.5988 com   36.2943 exp    4  356    9.5874 asp   36.6534 sca
175  0.99851  0.4197     9.6043 com   36.0974 exp    5  355    9.5865 asp   36.6557 sca
174  0.99786  0.5036     9.6110 com   35.8594 exp    6  354    9.5853 asp   36.6585 sca
```

This is what i get

```
177  0.99947  0.2519     9.5946 com   36.4488 exp    3  357    9.5882 asp   36.6517 sca 176  0.99905  0.3358     9.5988 com   36.2943 exp    4  356    9.5874 asp   36.6534 sca 175  0.99851  0.4197     9.6043 com   36.0974 exp    5  355    9.5865 asp   36.6557 sca 174  0.99786  0.5036     9.6110 com   35.8594 exp    6  354    9.5853 asp   36.6585 sca
```

It is the same output but with no newlines, is all in a row output
It is the well known compatibility problem between Linux and Windows:
linux use "\n" and windows use "\r\n" to write new lines

Is there a Gfortran flag to modify the output to be compatible with Windows? 
Is there another way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Which problems do you have? How do they exhibit? How do you write and read the files? We need to see the code that does the I/O. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I have 34 different .f90 files I can't post all, this files are made with the "write" command, I will edit my question enayway to be more specific

Comment: You still did not tell use **what kind of problems** you have. We do not have a crystal ball, really. Show us which read command causes the problem and specify the problem.

Comment: when i said "endline char compatibility" i thought it was clear sorry

Comment: i just modified my question to be much more clear

Comment: It's worth noting that any decent text editor on both Windows and Linux can deal with both styles of line endings without any problem, so if your problem is just looking at the generated file on Windows you can just use another editor (even WordPad will do).

Comment: And do you have any problem reading that file in Fortran? Have you tried it? Or is it just the appearance in Notepad (which is **terrible** text editor)?

Comment: I use Python to read it and no problems, others, in my company use VBA to read it and THEY got problems, that is why i'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gfortran and several other languages/runtimes on Windows should read your files just fine even with the Unix line terminations. You have to provide us with details of the error you actually have when reading in VBA or elsewhere, otherwise  we can't tell you how to avoid it.

*Is there another way to resolve this issue?*

Yes, you can run the well-known [unix2dos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) utility to convert the datafiles to DOS/Windows format. Or some alternative utility mentioned in the linked webpage.

Comment: Ok it was my bad, i didn't make it clear that I'm not reading the output file in Fortran but in others languages (VBA, Python, C++, Java)

Comment: Thank you very much for that utility that I didn't know